# Pandas asfreq with weekly frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have weekly data of logs for some devices. For some device it start on Monday, for some on Wednesday etc. Sometimes there are gaps of ~month in this data, but I want the DataFrame index to still contain rows for each week with NaN value.

I am trying to use `asfreq('W')` in Python, but I cannot get what I expect.

**Example:**

What I have:

```
Date            Some_Value
====            ==========
2019-04-10      2
2019-04-17      1
2019-04-24      3
2019-05-01      1
2019-05-08      3
2019-05-15      2
2019-06-06      3
2019-06-13      2
```

What I expect/want to have (note 2 new rows with NaNs):

```
Date            Some_Value
====            ==========
2019-04-10      2
2019-04-17      1
2019-04-24      3
2019-05-01      1
2019-05-08      3
2019-05-15      2
2019-05-22      NaN
2019-05-30      NaN
2019-06-06      3
2019-06-13      2
```

What I get with `asfreq('W')`:

```
Date            Some_Value
====            ==========
2019-03-31      NaN
2019-04-07      NaN
2019-04-14      NaN
...................
```

So, I get all `NaN` values and the dates from each Sunday. But I do not need dates from each Sunday. I need to take the first date of a DataFrame (of first row in a group in pandas' `groupby` in case of many time-series) and resample weekly form that first row.

Is it achievable directly with pandas `asfreq`? With some other pandas method? Or should it be some more complex custom function?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a datetime column? and is it: `df['Some_Value'].resample('W').sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in your data are first values in Wednesday, last 2 in Thursday, so asfreq return `NaN`s, because try change it to Sunday weekday freq - [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets):

> W-SUN  weekly frequency (Sundays). Same as **'W'**

One possible solution, but `DatetimeIndex` is changed for Sundays:

```
print (df.resample('W').first())
            Some_Value
Date                  
2019-04-14         2.0
2019-04-21         1.0
2019-04-28         3.0
2019-05-05         1.0
2019-05-12         3.0
2019-05-19         2.0
2019-05-26         NaN
2019-06-02         NaN
2019-06-09         3.0
2019-06-16         2.0
```

If change frequency in `asfreq`:

```
print (df.asfreq('W-Wed'))
            Some_Value
Date                  
2019-04-10         2.0
2019-04-17         1.0
2019-04-24         3.0
2019-05-01         1.0
2019-05-08         3.0
2019-05-15         2.0
2019-05-22         NaN
2019-05-29         NaN
2019-06-05         NaN
2019-06-12         NaN

print (df.asfreq('W-Thu'))
            Some_Value
Date                  
2019-04-11         NaN
2019-04-18         NaN
2019-04-25         NaN
2019-05-02         NaN
2019-05-09         NaN
2019-05-16         NaN
2019-05-23         NaN
2019-05-30         NaN
2019-06-06         3.0
2019-06-13         2.0
```

Comment: It does not matter to me if all data will look as if it came from Sunday. I just want to display 1 row per week. However, if I use `resample('W').first()`, it does not fill in missing weeks. For example, in my index I get 2019-04-29 and then 2019-06-03, while what I actually need is to have all weekly indices between them with `NaN` values. Or does it make sense to use `resample` chained with `asfreq`?

Comment: @Valeria - hmmm, I think main problem in data is mixed weekday frequencies, `resample` normalize them.

Comment: I found minor bug in my code. The solution with `resample('W').first()` is correct.