# Using Pandas asfreq(), I lose some days in the beginning and the end

Tags: pandas

```
ind = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(range(len([*ind])), index=ind)
df.asfreq('W').head()
```

[image]

I lost 1 day (2022-01-01) and the weeks starts Monday, leaving me with a standalone 1 day (2022-01-02).  Why do I lose 1 day ?  Why pandas does not combine with 2022-01-02 and have 2 days instead ?  How do I tell asfreq to align Sun-Sat instead of Mon-Sun ?

```
df.asfreq('W').tail()
```

[image]

Here I lost 2022-12-26 to 2022-12-31.  Why in the beginning, I get a standalone 1 day but when doing tail, it does not give me the 6 days ?

I cannot understand how asfreq works.  I hope somebody could explain.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas asfreq with weekly frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57490946/pandas-asfreq-with-weekly-frequency)

Answer (score 1):

See this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets) in the pandas documentation on date functionality.
You'll see, on default `'W'` starts with Sunday ("W-SUN weekly frequency (Sundays). Same as ‘W’"), so your `head()` and `tail()` will only display Sundays in the range of your `df`. If you want to start the week at a different day, use one of the other strings below that.